# Azure Service Fabric: cannot run Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a problem with Azure Service Fabric.

I have installed it (on Windows 7) as it was said in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/.

But when I try to run a Service Fabric application from Visual Studio  I see that Windows service Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe") fails to start.
This service hangs for several minutes and then finishes with the following error message:

*Faulting application name: FabricHost.exe, version: 5.0.217.100, time stamp: 0x571a85d8
Faulting module name: FabricHost.exe, version: 5.0.217.100, time stamp: 0x571a85d8
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x00000000000b3146
Faulting process id: 0xb34
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1b90822b3eb43
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\FabricHost.exe
Report Id: 0b7cff13-24fc-11e6-bccf-e06995ddb2c0*

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: make sure you have Windows firewall running on the server before you do anything else.

Once its running start the fabric service. Once Fabric Service is running you should be able to start the Front End service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I have already solved this problem with Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service by changing its Account from Local System to Network Service. It worked.
But – then I ran into another problem: I cannot start Service Fabric Cluster. It has been created (in folder c:\ SfDevCluster) OK. But then ,when Visual Studio tried to start Service Fabric Cluster, it got the following error:

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check 
if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue.

Comment: Make sure your SF is listening in port 19000. That is the default mgmnt port